# How to remove index.php from JQuery File Upload Demo PREVIEW FILES

Tags: jquery, file, upload, demo, blueimp

I have a photo uploading website and I Recently added an index.php to my photos directory.
But it also shows up in my jQuery File Upload. How to Remove It?

PS : See attached image[in link]...

http://www.pandhare.co.in/test/ERROR.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "remove" it from files list. For this you should fix php script on build list function. just don't include entry to list if the have substring ".php" in file name.

Comment: I had thought of it, But I Don't know where does it gets the files from...
Please Help Me Out..!